# How to Change MimeKit Asp.Net Core 2.0 Change BodyBuilder(); " {} " Selector

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I use mimekit to send e-mail. But in e-mail design there is a {} in css codes and I need to use a structure like {0}, {1} etc to print data with mimekit, and this structure is complicated by css {0} index, {{0} How to change it.

My Code;

```
var pathToFile = _enviorment.WebRootPath
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
                        + "Templates"
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
                        + "EmailTemplate"
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
                        + "Discount.html";

                    var builder = new BodyBuilder();


                    using (StreamReader SourceReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(pathToFile))
                    {
                        builder.HtmlBody = SourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    var messageBody = string.Format(builder.HtmlBody,
                     _strName,
                     _strSurname,
                     _discountCode
                     );
```

Error Message;

FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.